# Can I be vulnerable to SQL injection by appending input with no whitespace to my query?

Tags: security, sql-injection

I am taking in a string from user input, and splitting it on whitespace (using \w) into an array of strings.  I then loop through the array, and append a part of the where clause like this:

```
            query += " AND ( "

                 + "field1 LIKE '%" + searchStrings[i] +"%' "
                 + " OR field2 LIKE '%" + searchStrings[i] +"%' "
                 + " OR field3 LIKE '%" + searchStrings[i] +"%' "
                 + ") ";
```

I feel like this is dangerous, since I am appending user input to my query.  However, I know that there isn't any whitespace in any of the search strings, since I split the initial input on whitespace.

Is it possible to attack this via a SQL injection?  Giving `Robert');DROP TABLE students;--` wouldn't actually drop anything, since there needs to be whitespace in there.  In that example, it would not behave properly, but no damage would be done.

Can anyone with more experience fighting SQL injections help me either fix this, or put my mind at ease?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Wow, that is a lot of great input.  Thank you everyone who responded.  I will investigate full-text search and, at a minimum, parameterize my query.

Just so I can better understand the problem, would it be possible to inject if all whitespace **AND** single quotes were escaped?

Comment: Does \w cover all concievable whitespace?

It seems like it is just safer to attempt to wash the userdata prior to using it,

Comment: As other folks have illustrated, you're still vulnerable to SQL injection so you should escape the searchstrings.  But I also want to comment that you should be using a fulltext search engine instead of all those wildcard searches!

Comment: You can still encode single quotes using ASCII characterization, so I would say even still, don't take any chances!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any time you allow a user to enter data into a query string like this you are vulnerable to SQL injection and it should be avoided like the plague!

You should be very careful how you allow your searchStrings[] array to be populated.  You should always append variable data to your query using parameter objects:

```
+ field1 like @PropertyVal Or field2 like @PropertyVal Or field3 like @PropertyVal etc...
```

And if you're using SQL Server for example

```
Query.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PropertyVal", '%' + searchStrings[i] + '%'));
```

Be very wary how you build a query string that you're going to run against a production server, especially if it has any data of consequence in it!

In your example you mentioned Little Bobby Tables

Robert');DROP TABLE students;--

And cited that because it needs white space, you couldn't do it - but if the malicious user encoded it using something like this:

```
Robert');Exec(Replace('Drop_Table_students','_',Char(32)));--
```

I would say - better to be safe and do it the right way.  There's no simple way to make sure you catch every scenario otherwise...

Answer (score 13):

Yes, this script did not contain any whitespaces, just encoded characters that SQL decoded back and executed: 
http://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00001427.html

The injected script was something like this:

> DECLARE%20@S%20NVARCHAR(4000);SET%20@S=CAST(0x440045004300
>   4C00410052004500200040005400200076006100720063006800610072
>   00280032003500350029002C0040004300200076006100720063006800
>   610072002800320035003500290020004400450043004C004100520045
>   0020005400610062006C0065005F0043007500720073006F0072002000
>   43005500520053004F005200200046004F0052002000730065006C0065
>   0063007400200061002E006E0061006D0065002C0062002E006E006100
>   6D0065002000660072006F006D0020007300790073006F0062006A0065
>   00630074007300200061002C0073007900730063006F006C0075006D00
>   6E00730020006200200077006800650072006500200061002E00690064
>   003D0062002E0069006400200061006E006400200061002E0078007400
>   7900700065003D00270075002700200061006E0064002000280062002E
>   00780074007900700065003D003900390020006F007200200062002E00
>   780074007900700065003D003300350020006…

Wich SQL decoded to :

> DECLARE @T varchar(255)'@C
>   varchar(255) DECLARE Table_Cursor
>   CURSOR FOR select a.name'b.name from
>   sysobjects a'syscolumns b     where
>   a.id=b.id and a.xtype='u' and
>   (b.xtype=99 or b.xtype=35     or b…

and so on, so its possible to do whatever you want with every table in the database without using any whitespaces.

Comment: Okay, that's far more impressive than my injection example, but somewhat less readable :P

Comment: I thought a real life example of when hundreds of thounsands servers was infected, would be a good example to show. ;) 

I +1 your answer for pointing at the parameter-objects. (My solution is to only using strongly typed datasets with tableadapters.)

Answer (score 5):

There are just too many ways to get this wrong, that I wouldn't rely if anyone told me "no, this will be safe, because ..."

What about escaping the whitespace in some form (URL-Encode or somethign). What about using non-obvious Unicode whitespace characters that your simple tests don't check for. What if your DB supports some malicious operations that don't require a white space?

Do the correct way: Use a PreparedStatement (or whatever your platform uses for injection-safe parameterization), append and prepend the "%" to the user input and use that as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is: If the string you're appending isn't SQL, it **must** be escaped using prepared statements or the correct 'escape' function from your DB client library.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree that query parameters are the absolutely safest way to go. With them you have no risk of SQL injection whatsover (unless you do something stupid with the parameters) and there is no overhead of escaping.

If your DBMS does not support query parameters, then it MUST support string escaping. In the worst case you can try to escape single-quotes yourself, although there still is a Unicode exploit that can circumvent this. However, if your DBMS does not support query parameters, it probably doesn't support Unicode either. :)

**Added:** Also. queries like you wrote up there are killers for performance - no indexes can be used. I'd advise to look up your DBMS' full-text-indexing capabilities. They are meant exactly for cases such as this.

Comment: How could you inject if single quotes were also escaped?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they could still inject items, without spaces it might not do much, but it is still a vulnerability.

In general blindly adding user input to a query is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trivial injection, if I set field1 to this I've listed all rows in your database. This may be bad for security...

```
'+field1+'
```

You should use parameters (these are valid in inline SQL too), e.g.

```
AND Field1 = @Field1
```